# Methods Of Counting Non-trivial Zeros Of Zeta Function

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

What are the *different methods* using contour integration that can be used to count the non-trivial zeros of the zeta function?

I know of Backlund's exact formula which is similar to Riemann-von Mangoldt formula. What are the other ways?

If there aren't many other different methods, then where can I find the exact derivation, like from scratch to end of Riemann-von Mangoldt formula? I have managed half of it till the point I can derive Backlund's exact formula. Also an evaluation of the limitations would be nice.

I know Titchmarsh's works are useful but what other resources can help me?

Comment: _Riemann zeta function_ by H. M. Edwards.

Comment: @TravorLZH I do have that book. It has quite a bit of info. Other than the 2 estimates I mentioned, are there any other?